# Comet solution: Price and performance

Tags: comet

I'm about implementing a notification system in my webapp. I have to consider the price and performance for scaling. I know a few solutions that are great, stream-hub for example. But I don't know the price of it. Google it and it will not come up any prices. In the performance side, I had made some research and found that the Jetty server support continutation, which is great. I wanna pick the solution that is best. Does anyone with good experience on Comet solution know the best solution right now in terms of scaling a web app?

Comment: It strikes me as weird that there are boxed "comet" implementations.  It's really just a protocol (more like a technique) that is actually fairly easy to implement.  What sort of data are you trying to push out?

Comment: just simple text message - notifications.

Answer (score 2):

Jetty's a great solution; I know the developer, and he's really on the ball. If you're going for Java, that's your best bet.

For .NET, I favor WebSync (since I work for the comany that makes it) for scalability and ease of use; [I'm not alone in that belief](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604193/websync-pros-and-cons).

All that said - I'd say you want to pick the software you want based on your comfort level with the language first. If you're a Java guy running Apache, you probably don't want a solution that's .NET, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

There are important features you have to consider before choosing any of the available products.

1. Scalability
2. Client disconnection detection
3. Success in reverse ajax support
4. Cross domain support to get rid of the problems on IE6 or 7 (two connections per host)

So, based on your implementation platform, there are 2 choices i highly suggest;

1 - for ASP.NET & Mono : [**PokeIn**](http://pokein.codeplex.com) Library (helps you to break the limits on IIS and deserves the price)

2 - for JAVA : [**DWR**](http://directwebremoting.org/) (very good choice for Jetty and free)